# Query with ROWID via data provider

Tags: advantage-database-server

I am looking to query a table like the following sql:

`select * from itd093 where rowid='Cumn99AAAAMzAAAAAJ'`

It could find a unique record in the ADS architect client. However, when this query was sent from the code level through the .NET data provider, it return none result from the database server.

Does anyone have ideas on how I can make the sql above return the result through the .NET data provider?

Some sample code here:

```
        public void DataProviderTest()
        {
            using (AdsConnection conn = new AdsConnection(@"Data Source=D:\Development\FDDB;ServerType=ADS_LOCAL_SERVER;TableType=ADS_CDX;TrimTrailingSpaces=TRUE;"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                AdsCommand cmd = new AdsCommand("select * from itd093 where rowid='Cumn99AAAAMzAAAAAJ'", conn);

                AdsDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                if (!reader.Read())
                    throw new Exception("no records");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Whether you are submitting this query via Advantage Data Architect or via the .NET data provider, the execution at the server will be the same. If you can show a simple re-creation (some code) that you are using, it might help determine what is going on.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the reply. I add in some code above, which should return result but id didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Mark for pointing out that the .NET data provider and the Advantage Data Architect should return the same result.

The problem to be the different connection strings. From the help documentation, it says,**the first six characters of the ROWID represent the database ID. It is based on the connection path**.

I was mistakenly copy a rowid from the data architect to test with data provider, and the connection strings are different. That's why I couldn't get a result returned from the data provider as it does from the data architect.